# Issue with serial interface of Futaba LCD M162MD07aa-000

Tags: pcb, digital-logic, identification, protocol, character-lcd

I have purchased a Futaba LCD from Mouser,
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Futaba/M162MD07AA-000?qs=PzGy0jfpSMv5CfcVuWSnKw%3D%3D

It says in the datasheet that it supports three modes; I want to use the serial interface, so I configured it using this guide in the datasheet:

[image: JUMPER SETTINGS]

First of all I am confused with jumpers J2 and J3, as you can seen below:

[image: Image for j2 and j3]

If J2 and J3 are two horizontal jumpers or J3 is the vertical and J2 is top horizontal.

I tried both the settings and using the adafruit library, https://github.com/adafruit/SPI_VFD, but I am not getting any result on the LCD.

Please share your thoughts if anyone has suggestions or relevant experience.

**Update**
If you have M162MD07aa-000 VFD, you can use SPI_VFD library of LCD by configuring the LCD in serial mode. I had just gnd wire issue, It was not soldered properly.
Thanks

Comment: J3 is vertical, J2 is horizontal. The other horizontal part below J2 is C63.

Comment: alright, but it is not working at all. although I have generated same protocol that is mentioned in it's datasheet. may be I am skipping anything. I have attached the link for library I am using.

Comment: It worked, thanks for your response